# Undefined reference to : cellAtIndex(int) ? implicit conversion?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

It seems like it isn't the matter of usual "undefined reference to :.....".
I think it might be related to implicit conversion. 
I put the codes below in HelloWorldScene.h

```
ssize_t cellNumb;
cocos2d::extension::TableView* itemSlots;
```

Every time I try to use

```
itemSlots->cellAtIndex(cellNumb);
```

in cpp, an error occurs just in compiling apk file. not in the debug mode in VS.

[image: compile error]

I think it's very weird that debugging project with that code goes just fine. That error occurs only when making apk file. This is very uncommon case, isn't it? Why the ssize_t variable turns int suddenly? It is obvious that method cellAtIndex needs ssize_t. that's why I declared cellNumb as ssize_t!

I tried also like this :

```
itemSlots->cellAtIndex((ssize_t) cellNumb);
```

and also this :

```
itemSlots->cellAtIndex(static_cast <ssize_t> cellNumb);
```

I also changed above ssize_t into size_t , long int, unsigned int, etc. but every trial gone fail. I searched hundred times but I fail to find proper answer matched with my case.

I checked and add all cpp files in Anroid.mk, and SDK JDK NDK ANT.. they are well installed and debugging in VS 2015 also clear.

Comment: are you sure you have the .lib added to your project?

Comment: what do you mean by .lib? operating project in VS is always fine here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you upgraded your cocos2d-x library but you still have some old Android related files lying around (maybe makefiles).

Comment: how can I erase those old files?

Comment: If you've just replaced the contents of the *cocos2d* directory, I would suspect something is wrong in *proj.android* or *proj.android-studio* depending on which IDE you're using. I'd create an empty new project with the latest version of cocos2d-x and then use a *diff* application to see any differences between your project and the new one. Something like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en) should help you.

Comment: thank you for your advise.. I kept trying to check by using WinMerge yesterday but I struggled so many times without figuring out exactly so I decided to reinstall cocos2d-x in latest version. it takes a long time also but that helps me eventually not to see that errors again. I'm very happy now. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

include header file

## include "cocos-ext.h"

Comment: I did it of coursely when I start to make my project

Comment: your cocos2d-x version?